# Deleting duplicate LibreOffice programs

Tags: 18.04, libreoffice, software-uninstall

I have Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS
It came preinstalled with LibreOffice Draw, Calc, Impress and Writer. I downloaded LibreOffice Base from the Ubuntu Software app, but it installed the full suite of LibreOffice programs.

I tried to delete the duplicate programs through Ubuntu Software, but after pressing remove, they were still there.

Does anyone know how to remove the duplicate programs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since 18.04, a new way of distributing software was introduced. It concerns the SNAP package format. You actually will find two different entries for Libreoffice, one version distributed via the conventional APT system, and a version (usually more recent) distributed through SNAP. Both versions can co-exist together. You may have both of them installed.

The Base component of Libreoffice does not have a separate entry. Thus, looking for "libreoffice base", your probably encountered the SNAP package of libreoffice. There seems not to be a way of installing only Base of the APT version through Software.

- Open Software, and locate the package "Libreoffice". clicking on it, you can see in the details if it is a SNAP (As Source, "Snap Store" is indicated) or an APT version (as source, a repository is mentionned such as ubuntu-bionic-updates-main), Remove the Snap version.
- This leaves you with only the APT version, but without base, which is not installed by default. Install the base component with the terminal command: `sudo apt install libreoffice-base`.

If instead you prefer the SNAP version, then remove the Writer, Calc, Draw and Impress packages of the regular version using Software center, and install the LibreOffice SNAP version.